# What's the difference between the two methods of using sub-model in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

method 1:

```
class subnet1():
    def __init__()

class subnet2():
    def __init__()

class father_net():
    def __init__():
        self.n1 = subnet1()
        self.n2 = subnet2()
    def forward():
        x = self.n1()
        x = self.n2(x)
```

method 2:

```
class father_net():
    def subnet1():
    def subnet2():
    def forward():
        x = self.subnet1()
        x = self.subnet2()
```

It seems nothing different when I train `father_net`.

However I still want to get some detail explanations. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From object-oriented perspective, method 1 implements the two sub-nets as objects and the forward pass through the nets as a behavior. While in method 2, the two sub-nets are defined as the behavior of father-net object, and hence defined as methods.

From execution perspective, both are same, but it makes more sense to consider sub-nets as entities (objects) and have their respective forward pass (and backward pass) as their respective behavior.

One scenario where method-2 might more meaningful is when you have to explicitly constrain your sub-nets to be only used by `father_net`.

Comment: I would argue that it depends on whether or not you use the sub-routines of the `subnet` functions outside of your `father_net` or not. If not, then the two sub-routines are simply a property that should not be shared with other networks, as would be possible in the first instance